# Node JS return image in rest api response

Tags: node.js, rest, express, postman

On the rest api call of get user information I want to return user information along with image. Can anyone please tell how to return the image along with the information in node js. Also how I can see the information returned in web client like postman.

Answer (score 16):

If you want to send image as binary data, you can use the built in [`res.sendFile`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.sendFile) function.

If you want this image to only be available to the current user, you can use a authorization framework like [passportjs](http://passportjs.org/) or even high level frameworks such as [huntjs](http://huntjs.herokuapp.com/) with all things included.

Below is an example that checks that `req.user` exists and then sends either `JSON` with a link to the image or the image itself.
If the image is small it may be better to send a [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data:_URL) encoded version.

```
app.get('/info', function(req,res){
    if(req.user){
        res.status(200).json({
            'imageName':'some image',
            'imageUrl':'/someImageUrlOnlyForAuthorizedUsers.jpg'
        });
    } else {
        res.status(401).send('Authorization required!');
    }
});

app.get('/someImageUrlOnlyForAuthorizedUsers.jpg', function(req,res){
    if(req.user){
        res.sendFile('./mySecretImage.jpg');
    } else {
        res.status(401).send('Authorization required!');
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks, but if I send the direct url of the image then there could be a security threat that anyone can access that image.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. One more thing can I send json response and file at the same time. i mean i want to return user information and the picture of the user can it be done with the same response?

Comment: yes. If user's avatar is quite small, you can encode it using base64 and serve it as <img src="data: ..."> - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data:_URL